# How to search for all occurrences of a word in all Report Files?

Tags: search, crystal-reports, cpu-word

1. All reports are located under a folder on the drive (around 1800)

   1.a. The reports may have more than one query, and may have sub-reports too
2. Some of the reports (well over a 100) reference a particular field in the database
3. The field-name on the database is changed

I'm looking for a way to find the names of all RPT files where this field-name occurs as a precursor to modifying the queries.

What I have done so far is to try to use windows search in files for the specific word ...

How would you discover all RPT files that contain a particular word?

Regards,
Ev1

Comment: Offtopic, but you should never change field names in database... This way you kill all views, procedures, functions, reports and whatever other components use these fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the co-founders of Find it EZ Software. There are some commercial products like FinditEZ Code Search Pro that are specifically designed to deliver what you are looking for. A free trial of our product is available. See http://www.finditez.com/crystalreports for more details.

Find it EZ is one of several Crystal Report management tools reviewed and that may meet your needs @ http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/rpt-management-utilities .

Find it EZ is a change impact analysis search tool for Crystal .rpt files and underlying databases. It includes the ability to search for specific word or string matches as well as several canned reports that can extract embedded SQL code or create xref lists for all referenced tables and field names used in your library of Cyrstal reports.

Comment: "Change Impact Anaylsis for Business Intelligence Reports" on the site has a spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to accomplish - CR files (at least starting from version 9 or 9.5) are compressed.
We created simple executable, opening reports as objects and exporting their content in "report definition file" format (internally simple text file). This way most fields and formula contents, used on report and subreports, are exported in textual format - unfortunately formulas, which are not directly placed on report, but only used indirectly, are ignored.

Afterwards you can use windows search or grep or any other tools to search files, containing needed words.

Answer (score -1):

The old command **FindStr**! Use **Start|Run**, enter **CMD** and click **OK**.

Enter something like

```
findstr  /l /m "REFERENCE NUMBER" "C:\Reports\*.doc*"
```

to see the file names. And they say DOS is dead.